# Datagrid not adding a new row by pressing Enter or Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a datagrid, in which `CanUserAddRows = "true"`.

when I run the program, I get a blank row. When I enter data in that row, it works perfectly well. But After that if I try to add new row, I cannot add it, because I don't get a blank row by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

Here is the Page in which my datagrid resides :

```
<Page x:Class="WPF_Client.Pages.Masters.Multiple.Groups"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:WPF_Client.HelperClasses"
      xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WPF_Client.ViewModels.Masters.Multiple"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="760" d:DesignWidth="1366"
      Title="Groups">

    <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:GroupsViewModel />
    </Page.DataContext>

    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection" Source="{Binding GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects}" />
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <CompositeCollection x:Key="Items">
                    <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Background="#FF2A2A2A" Foreground="White">
                        <Grid TextElement.FontWeight="Bold" >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.Children>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Group Name" />
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Effect" />
                            </Grid.Children>
                        </Grid>
                    </ComboBoxItem>
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffectsCollection}}" />
                </CompositeCollection>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type helpers:GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.Children>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding GroupName}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding CorrespondingEffect}" />
                        </Grid.Children>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name" Width="2*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding GroupName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Group" Width="2*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Items}" 
                                      SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedGroupID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}"
                                      SelectedValuePath="GroupID" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" TextSearch.TextPath="GroupName">
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Effect" Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Effects, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" DisplayMemberPath="Effect" 
                                                            SelectedValue="{Binding DataContext.SelectedEffectID, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" SelectedValuePath="EffectID"
                                      Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedGroupID, 
                                                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}},
                                                             Converter={StaticResource effectsVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

Here is my ViewModel :

```
public class GroupsViewModel : ViewModelBase, IModule
{
    public GroupsViewModel()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Add((IModule)this);

        Groups = new ObservableCollection<Group>();

        using (Entities db = new Entities())
        {
            List<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect> _GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = (
                                                                                             from g in db.Groups
                                                                                             select new GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect
                                                                                             {
                                                                                                 GroupID = g.GroupID,
                                                                                                 GroupName = g.GroupName,
                                                                                                 CorrespondingEffect = g.Master_Effects.Effect
                                                                                             }
                                                                                         ).ToList();

            GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects
                = new ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect>(
                                                                                _GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects.Where
                                                                                    (
                                                                                        u => !StaticMethods.GetAllChildren(25)
                                                                                                .Select(x => x.GroupID)
                                                                                                .Contains(u.GroupID)
                                                                                    ).ToList()
                                                                            );

            Effects = new ObservableCollection<Master_Effects>(from m in db.Master_Effects
                                                               select m);
        }
    }

    ~GroupsViewModel()
    {
        SessionViewModel.Instance.ModulesOpen.Remove((IModule)this);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Group> _groups;
    public ObservableCollection<Group> Groups
    {
        get
        {
            return _groups;
        }
        set
        {
            _groups = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect> _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
    public ObservableCollection<GroupNameWithCorrespondingEffect> GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects
    {
        get
        {
            return _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects;
        }
        set
        {
            _groupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("GroupNamesWithCorrespondingEffects");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedGroupID;
    public int SelectedGroupID
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedGroupID;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedGroupID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedGroupID");
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Master_Effects> _effects;
    public ObservableCollection<Master_Effects> Effects
    {
        get
        {
            return _effects;
        }
        set
        {
            _effects = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Effects");
        }
    }

    private int _selectedEffectID;
    public int SelectedEffectID
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedEffectID;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedEffectID = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedEffectID");
        }
    }

    public string ModuleFriendlyName
    {
        get { return "GroupsViewModel"; }
    }

    public string ModuleName
    {
        get { return "Groups"; }
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Or is it the default behavior of dataGrid?

**Update:**

I have updated my code as per your suggestions. Here is my xaml :

```
<DataGrid ..............>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewKeyDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.NewRowCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Page}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</DataGrid>
```

Here is my ViewModel :

//In Constructor :
NewRowCommand = new RelayCommand(NewRow);

//In Body:

```
public ICommand NewRowCommand { get; set; }

private void NewRow(object obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show("PreviewKeyDown on Datagrid invoked.");
}
```

I successsfully get MessageBox in the output when I press any key on DataGrid's input area.

**Problem After Update:**

Now, after trying your suggested points, I also got some problems.

I want to show that messagebox only when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> (if it is the default behaviour on the grid. I don't know the default behaviour because I am very new to DataGrid.) key on the DataGrid. So, my actual problem is to identify the key that is pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to "route" that keystrokes event to some ViewModel method that add a new item to the collection. At the end of such method you have to call OnPropertyChanged to reflect the new item in the View.

EDIT

1. Reference the assembly System.Windows.Interactivity
2. Add **xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"** to your xaml declaration
3. Use it:

`<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>`

More details take a look to this links:

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125188/Using-EventTrigger-in-XAML-for-MVVM-No-Code-Behind)  and [here](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/)

EDIT 2:

> I see the problem, InputBindings will do the job in such cases:

```
<DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding NewRowCommand }"/>
</DataGrid.InputBindings>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Can you show me any example or tutorial? Also, as you say I should route keystrokes, then can you explain me the purpose of CanUserAddRows property of DataGrid?

Comment: Thanks for the update. It helped me. Now I have used PreviewKeyDown Event and bound the command to it. I will update my code with the latest update.